# How to perform a sub query for a Navigation Property in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Following is my code. I want to select a specific guest from Guests list of an invitation. But the following code throws the following error. How can I achieve this? I saw in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439872/how-to-include-all-underlying-navigation-properties-automatically-with-entity-fr?answertab=votes#tab-top) there are some similar answers but not sure how to adapt it into EF Core.

**Error: "Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid."**

```
invitation = await _dbContext.Invitations
                                            .Include(s => s.Host)
                                            .Include(s => s.Guests.Where(g => g.GuestId.ToString().Equals(model.GuestId)))
                                            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.InvitationId.ToString().Equals(model.InvitationId));
```

Comment: So you want a bunch of invitations, where its guest collection has just the one guest in it (determined by the id you supplied)? If not, you need to be specific about what you actually want

Comment: @MichaelRandall Yep. Correct. I don't want the whole guests list. I only want the guest I specify.

Comment: Look at this article [Include With Where Clause](https://entityframework.net/include-with-where-clause). It also links to a related SO question.

Comment: @downernn I've seen it. It doesn't work. At least in EF Core.

Comment: What is the problem you're facing? Does it have something to do with lazy loading, as discussed in [the related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798796/ef-include-with-where-clause)? Would you like to share the code you wrote based on this approach?

Answer (score 4):

The other answer posted by thatsalok is correct, an `Include` cannot be filtered. However, there are still ways to achieve what you want.

`Include` statements don't allow for filtering, but `Select` statements do. This means that you can ask EF to give you exactly what you want.

```
var result = await _dbContext
                       .Invitations
                       .Where(i => i.InvitationId.ToString().Equals(model.InvitationId))
                       .Select(i => new
                           {
                               Invitation = i,
                               Guest = i.Guests.FirstOrDefault(g => g.GuestId.ToString().Equals(model.GuestId))
                           })
                       .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

// demo usage
var invitation = result.Invitation;
var guest = result.Guest;
```

I strongly advise not using the entity class itself to store a limited list, as this may become a source of bugs if this entity will still be used in the database context. Instead, use a purpose built DTO (or viewmodel) class that contains the guest and invitation objects separately.

Comment: Thanks! This is very close to what I want but not quite it. Because this still contains the original invitation with unwanted Guests, you take out the matching Guest and put it into a different field.

Comment: My intention is to filter the unwanted Guests and still maintain the original object so I don't have to change the underlying logic. If I change the code as follows, it does what I want with some extra effort to map all the properties. .Select(i => new Invitation
                       {
                           //Map all individual properties
                           InvitationId = i.InvitationId,
                           Guests = new List<Guest> { i.Guests.FirstOrDefault(g => g.GuestId.ToString().Equals(model.GuestId)) }
                       })

Comment: @Heshan: It can be done, the exact way you want it to be done, but it's not advisable as entities are supposed to represent the database, not your custom domain logic (or its representative DTO objects). Just because it fits doesn't mean it belongs.

Answer (score 1):

After using EF core for almost the year,  having limited set of records in navigation property is not possible at least with EntityFramework Core 3.1.

However there are some third party provider who provide this type of capability like mentioned by @downernn in comment [Include with where clause](https://entityframework.net/include-with-where-clause)

There other officially supported extension for EF core, you may want to browse this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/) at MSDN

Comment: Thanks for the info. I commented on the above answer on how I managed to do what I want. Maybe not the cleanest way but can't find a better way as of now.